# How to make Puppeteer or Playwright to work on Azure Web App Service (Linux )

Tags: node.js, linux, azure-web-app-service, puppeteer, playwright

I am using Puppeteer to convert the web page into pdf when I run the code in my local it works fine completely but when I push the code to Azure Linux Web App service I am getting an error.

Code used :

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto(
      `https://${env.domain}/authorize? 
       client_id=${env.clientId}&response_type=token&redirect_uri=${env.redirectUri}`,
      { waitUntil: "networkidle2" }
    );
await page.waitForSelector('input[name="email"]', {
      visible: true,
      timeout: 5000
    });
await page.type('input[name="email"]', env.email, {delay: 50});
await page.type('input[name="password"]', env.password, {delay: 50});
await page.click('button[type="submit"]');
await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: "networkidle2" });
const clientUrl = await page.evaluate(() => window.location.href);
await page.pdf({path: 'sendgrid/html-page.pdf', format: 'A4'});
await browser.close();
```

I have tried changing my code everything works fine in local but whenever I deploy it to webapp I getting below errors

error 1:

```
Could not find browser revision 818858. Run "PUPPETEER_PRODUCT=firefox npm install" or "PUPPETEER_PRODUCT=firefox yarn
install" to download a supported Firefox browser binary.
```

error 2:

```
/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-782078/chrome-linux/chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libgobject-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Is there any solution to fix this issue

Comment: Did you try run `npm install` in kudu?   
  https://{yourwebappname}.scm.azurewebsites.net/kududebug

Comment: @DorisLv I tried a different workaround for this and it worked. I deployed the code in Windows Azure VM and installed the required packages and it worked fine for me. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

In case someone have the same issue I tested a simple working solution on Azure with Node12. You just need to launch the ssh terminal in your Azure App Service>Developement tools>SSH and apt-get install the necessary packages.

Example for "libgobject-2.0.so.0" the second Google result point to this page https://packages.debian.org/cgi-bin/search_contents.pl?word=libgobject-2.0.so.0&searchmode=searchfiles&case=insensitive&version=unstable&arch=i386 where you see that the package to install is "libglib2.0-0" so run "apt-get install libglib2.0-0" and voilà. You'll probably have other errors so repeat the process.